# SVN上にあるUnityのプロジェクト（BR）をURPの環境に切り替えたいときどのように行えばよいでしょうか？

Tags: unity3d, svn

複数人でゲーム開発をUnityでしている状況です。開発初めはビルトインレンダーパイプラインで作成していました。最近になりシェーダーグラフの使用が必要なためURPに切り替えるべく必要が出たためローカルで一度行い問題なく切り替えることができました。しかしSVN上でどのようにして共有すれば全員に滞りなくURP環境に切り替えられるかの方法がわからず困っています。